# Hangman printing in correct order

Tags: python

Hi im 2 weeks into my python class at school and i made a simple hangman type game heres the code

```
 secret = "computers"
    my_string = ""
    guesses = 10
    welcome = input("Welcome to hangman, whats your name? ")

    print("Hi " + welcome + " lets get started.")
    secret = "computers"
    my_string = ""
    guesses = 10
    welcome = input("Welcome to hangman, whats your name? ")
    print("Hi " + welcome + " lets get started.")
    while guesses >= 0:
        guess = input("Guess a letter: ")
        if guess in secret:
            print("Correct")
            my_string = my_string + guess
            print(my_string)
        elif guess not in secret:
            print("incorrect")
            guesses = guesses - 1
            print("You have " + str(guesses) + " left.")
        if my_string == "computer":
            print("Congrats you won!")
            break
        if guesses == -1:
            print("You lost.")
            break
```

the problem is that once i type a letter it does not print in the correct order. For example if I type "o" first and then guess the rest in the correct order it will print "ocmputers" if anyone can help i would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are new I would like to help you with a better version of hangman. The code below is chopped and changed version of your hangman. This is the code:

```
def choose_word():
    word = 'computers'
    return {'word':word, 'length':len(word)}

def guess_letter(word_, hidden_word_, no_guesses_, letters_):
    print('---------------------------------------')
    print('You have', no_guesses_, 'guesses left.')
    print('Available letters:', letters_)

    guess = input("Please guess a letter:")
    guess = guess.lower()

    if guess in letters_:
        letters_ = letters_.replace(guess, '')

        if guess in word_:
            progress = list(hidden_word_)
            character_position = -1
            for character in word_:
                character_position += 1
                if guess == character:
                    progress[character_position] = guess
            hidden_word_ = ''.join(progress)
            print('Good guess =', hidden_word_)
        else:
            print('Oops! That letter is not in my word:', hidden_word_)
            no_guesses_ = no_guesses_ - 1
    else:
        print('The letter "', guess, '" was already used!')
        no_guesses_ = no_guesses_ - 1

    if hidden_word_ == word_:
        print('Congratulations, you won!')
        return True
    if no_guesses_ == 0 and hidden_word_ != word_:
        print('Game over! Try again!')
        return False
    return guess_letter(word_, hidden_word_, no_guesses_, letters_)

def hangman():
    hangman_word = choose_word()
    print('Welcome to the game, Hangman!')
    print('I am thinking of a word that is', hangman_word['length'], 'letters long.')

    hidden_word = ''.join(['_'] * hangman_word['length'])
    no_guesses = 8
    letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

    guess_letter(hangman_word['word'], hidden_word, no_guesses, letters)

hangman()
```

Answer (score 0):

You build the output sting this way:

```
my_string = my_string + guess
```

So you just put the correctly guessed letters one after another in the order they were guessed disregarding thier order in the secrete word.

Answer (score 0):

Your conflicting lines are these ones

```
if guess in secret:
    print("Correct")
    my_string = my_string + guess
```

If you look closely, when you first add a letter, lets say `o`, `my_string` is empty, and then you add to it `guess` variable.

```
>>> print(my_string)
"o"
```

and then if you add `c`

```
>>> print(my_string)
"oc"
```

I would recommend having a different method for checking if you have entered a char of the secret word.